# Equivalent of Haskell scanl in python

Tags: python, haskell, functional-programming

I would like to know if there is a built in function in python for the equivalent Haskell `scanl`, as `reduce` is the equivalent of `foldl`.

Something that does this:

```
Prelude> scanl (+) 0 [1 ..10]
[0,1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45,55]
```

The question is not about how to implement it, I already have 2 implementations, shown below (however, if you have a more elegant one please feel free to show it here).

First implementation:

```
 # Inefficient, uses reduce multiple times
 def scanl(f, base, l):
   ls = [l[0:i] for i in range(1, len(l) + 1)]
   return [base] + [reduce(f, x, base) for x in ls]

  print scanl(operator.add, 0, range(1, 11))
```

Gives:

```
[0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55]
```

Second implementation:

```
 # Efficient, using an accumulator
 def scanl2(f, base, l):
   res = [base]
   acc = base
   for x in l:
     acc = f(acc, x)
     res += [acc]
   return res

 print scanl2(operator.add, 0, range(1, 11))
```

Gives:

```
[0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55]
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use this, if its more elegant:

```
def scanl(f, base, l):
    for x in l:
        base = f(base, x)
        yield base
```

Use it like:

```
import operator
list(scanl(operator.add, 0, range(1,11)))
```

Python 3.x has [`itertools.accumulate(iterable, func= operator.add)`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate). It is implemented as below. The implementation might give you ideas:

```
def accumulate(iterable, func=operator.add):
    'Return running totals'
    # accumulate([1,2,3,4,5]) --> 1 3 6 10 15
    # accumulate([1,2,3,4,5], operator.mul) --> 1 2 6 24 120
    it = iter(iterable)
    total = next(it)
    yield total
    for element in it:
        total = func(total, element)
        yield total
```

Comment: I don't know python, but shouldn't you have a `yield` statement before the `for` loop? `scanl` should return a list one item longer than the input list.

Comment: @rampion You are right, Haskell's `scanl` includes the initial accumulator. A `yield base` is missing.

Comment: @rampion all you need to do is change `for x in l` to `for x in [base] + l`

Answer (score 6):

Starting `Python 3.8`, and the introduction of [assignment expressions (PEP 572)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (`:=` operator), which gives the possibility to name the result of an expression, we can use a list comprehension to replicate a *scan left* operation:

```
acc = 0
scanned = [acc := acc + x for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
# scanned = [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

---

Or in a generic way, given a list, a reducing function and an initialized accumulator:

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
f = lambda acc, x: acc + x
accumulator = 0
```

we can scan `items` from the left and reduce them with `f`:

```
scanned = [accumulator := f(accumulator, x) for x in items]
# scanned = [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need. This version uses the python list comprehension

```
def scanl(data):
    '''
    returns list of successive reduced values from the list (see haskell foldl)
    '''
    return [0] + [sum(data[:(k+1)]) for (k,v) in enumerate(data)]


>>> scanl(range(1,11))
```

gives:

```
[0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55]
```

Comment: I would pass sum as a function argument to the scanl function.

Comment: This is not exactly `scanl`, because 


  (1) using the operator for `[:(k+1)]` is O(n) every time, so you have O(n^2) complexity here, which isn't the case for a real `scanl` 


  (2) assumption is that `sum` is used.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, the Python ecosystem is also overflowing with solutions:

Toolz has an accumulate capable of taking a user-supplied function as an argument.  I tested it with lambda expressions.

https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz/blob/master/toolz/itertoolz.py

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/toolz

as does more_itertools

http://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html

I did not test the version from more-itertools, but it also can take a user-supplied function.