# adding each element of list and then printing them scucessively

Tags: python

I have a list name:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to output to look like this, `1, 3(1+2),6(1+2+3), 10(1+2+3+4), ...` 
how can I do this in python? Thank for reply in advance

Comment: for i in range(0,len(list)):
        old_a=a
        old_b =b
        a=old_b
        b=old_a+old_b
        print a,b

Comment: I tried like this but i am getting sum of the last two elements of list. can we define any function for this and call that function.

Comment: Do you actually need the brackets in your output?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/14423794/989121

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.2+ it's as simple as this:

```
>>> from itertools import accumulate
>>> nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> list(accumulate(nums))
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21]
```

[Documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)

Answer (score 2):

```
total = 0
for i, element in enumerate(my_list):
    total += element
    print "%d (%s)" % (total, '+'.join(my_list[:i+1])
```

Comment: This was assuming you wanted the '(1+2)' in the actual output.  Otherwise, I'd go with @jamylak's answer.

Comment: My answer only works on 3.2+, I misinterpreted the question but this is probably what OP actually wants

Comment: @user1407199 I'm not exactly sure what OP wants now but either way OP should be covered

Answer (score 1):

Try this one-liner:

```
b = [sum(a[:i+1]) for i, x in enumerate(a)]
```

This is not super-efficient (and that's an understatement), because you are summing again and again the entire elements...

for a more efficient solution you can do something like this:

```
result = []

for i, current in enumerate(a):
    if result:
        last = result[i - 1]
    else:
        last = 0
    result.append(last + current)

print(result)
>> [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21]
```

Comment: Great for a one liner but horrible for huge lists