# What is the Ruby equivalent of Haskell's scanl?

Tags: ruby

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423794/equivalent-of-haskell-scanl-in-python) presents a version of Haskell's `scanl` in Python, but is there a Ruby version of this function?

Comment: Cool. And what is your question so far?

Comment: i can rephrase, if that helps? i wondered if there was a way to do it without writing my own function, or if there is a best way to write the function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably a nicer version could be written, but this is what I came up with:

```
require 'spec_helper'

class Array
  def scanl accumulator, &block
    results = [accumulator] + self
    results.each_with_index do |e, i|
      results[i] = block.call(accumulator, e)
      accumulator = results[i]
    end
    results
  end
end

describe "#scanl" do
  it 'is similar to foldl, but returns a list of successive reduced values from the left' do
    # example from http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions
    expect([3, 5, 2, 1].scanl(0, &:+)).to eq([0,3,8,10,11])
  end
end
```

I considered changing `scanl` to take just a method name like `:+` instead of a block to be more like `reduce`. Thoughts?

Comment: Come chat here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor . I think we can work out something

Comment: Just compare the quality of the questions.

Comment: Just as a FYI, deleting questions to preserve reputation isn't the best solution. Instead, fix the question so it's a better one. Think of it this way, questions are owned by the SO community once you ask them. We'll delete them if necessary.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ah, i thought it was more correct to put my potential solution in the Answer spot than the Question. i'll do better next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce()` and implement it by yourself.

```
def scanl(op, init, range)
  op = op.to_proc unless op.is_a?(Proc)
  range.reduce([init]) { |a, e| a.push(op.call(a.last,e)) }
end

p scanl(lambda { |a, b| a + b }, 0, 1..10)
#=> [0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55]
p scanl(:+, 0, 1..10)
#=> [0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55]
```

Alternatively you can use `map()` and put the initial element in front of the array.

```
def scanl(op, init, range)                             
  op = op.to_proc unless op.is_a?(Proc)                
  acc = init                                           
  range.map { |e| acc = op.call(acc, e) }.unshift(init)
end
```

Comment: nice i had a feeling i could piggy-back on reduce somehow. do you have to do the `is_a?(Proc)` check? i'd figure it'd be a no-op if it was already a proc and thus safe

Comment: yeah i mean that you can just run `.to_proc` always, if it is a proc, no-op, if it isn't, then you made it a proc, no?

Comment: although it is less concise, i think i prefer my version for the reason @SergioTulentsev points out. though the `to_proc` bit is helpful

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I updated my answer and replaced `Array#+` by `Array#push`.

Comment: @AlexMoore-Niemi You are rigth with `to_proc` call. The condition don't changes the behavoir. The condition makes the intention clearer, maybe. ;-)

Comment: "nice i had a feeling i could piggy-back on reduce somehow" – That's a pretty boring feeling, since `reduce` is general ;-) IOW: it can do *everything* a loop can do, and so you can *always* piggy-back on it. There's a proof sketch in Haskell on the Wikipedia page for `Fold`, if you're interested. The gist is this: a collection can be either empty or not. The two arguments to `reduce` (the initial and the block) tell it what to do with an empty collection and what to do with a not-empty collection. Since you have all cases covered, there is nothing `reduce` can't do. I once re-wrote all of …

Comment: `Enumerable` using `inject` instead of `each`, just for fun.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby 2.0, where the `Enumerator` class exists, we can build a nicer implementation that works properly with infinite ranges:

```rb
def scanl(elem, &op)
  Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    acc = elem
    loop do
      yielder << acc
      acc = op.call(acc)
    end
  end.lazy
end
```

And use it like so:

```rb
scanl(1, &:next).take(10)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
#=> #<Enumerator::Lazy: ...>
scanl(1, &:next).take(10).force                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
fib = scanl([0,1]) {|x, y| [y, x + y]}.map(&:first)
fib.take(10).force
#=> [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

Comment: this is more like `unfold`

Answer (score 0):

Operating with plain arrays:

```rb
class Array
  def scanl(init, &f)
    return [init] if empty?
    reduce([init]){ |xs, x| xs << f.(xs.last, x) }
  end
  
  def scanl1(&f)
    return if empty?  # might consider returning []
    x, *xs = self
    xs.scanl(x, &f)
  end
end
```

Generalized to `Enumerable`, returning `Enumerator`s:

```rb
module Enumerable
  def self._scanl(enum, a, &f)
    Enumerator.new do |y|
      y << a
      loop { b = enum.next; y << (a = f.(a, b)) }
    end
  end

  def scanl(a, &f)
    enum = each_entry
    Enumerable._scanl(enum, a, &f)
  end

  def scanl1(&f)
    enum = each_entry
    init = enum.next rescue return # might consider returning [].each_entry
    Enumerable._scanl(enum, init, &f)
  end
end
```

Examples:

```rb
[5].scanl(4) {|*a| a.max }&.to_a            # => [4, 5]
[1,2].scanl(4) {|*a| a.max }&.to_a          # => [4, 4, 4]
[1,2,3,5,3,7].scanl(4) {|*a| a.max }&.to_a  # => [4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7]

[].scanl1(&:+)&.to_a         # => nil
[1].scanl1(&:+)&.to_a        # => [1]
[1,2].scanl1(&:+)&.to_a      # => [1, 3]
[1,2,3,4].scanl1(&:+)&.to_a  # => [1, 3, 6, 10]
```